# the best way to keep the font-size the same on all devices

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, typography

I am struggling with setting up the font-size so it looks similar in all desktop devices.
For now the problem is that on my new laptop sidebar ends on 75% of total web height and on my old laptop it is exceeding 100% of screen height and I had to implement scrollbar. Is there anything I can do to prevent from it and to keep it the same. I tried these [2 solutions](https://bootstrapcreative.com/can-adjust-text-size-bootstrap-responsive-design/) but they don't work].

I am using default Bootstrap 5 typography. I am using h1-h6 and p tags on all websites. No custom font sizes and classes applied.

Comment: look into css media queries

Comment: Please see [ask]. You haven't provided enough information or clarity. I'm not sure at all what the height of a sidebar has to do with font sizes. Please provide a demo snippet.